# mysql query sorting and ordering

Tags: mysql, optimization

Say i have a table called "users" and it has 40 rows of records, each row has fields:

```
id, firstname, group_id, login_count, stay_on_page_count
```

groups has

```
administrator (1), manager (2), employee (3)
```

is it possible to create a query that will sort and order the rows this way

```
    group _id      stay_on_page_count  login_count
    =========      ==================  ===========
    1              100mins             100
    1              90mins              90
    2              100mins             100
    3              100mins             100

    1              80mins              80
    1              70mins              70
    2              90mins              90
    3              90mins              90

    1              60mins              60
    1              50mins              50
    2              80mins              80
    3              80mins              80

    1              40mins              40
    1              30mins              30
    2              70mins              70
    3              70mins              70
```

Basically I would like to create a 4x4 grid view using the query result. the pseudo code is probably

```
SELECT all FROM user table and to group the result in to cluster of 4, 
    while each 4 should have ORDER BY group_id ASC as first priority (1,1,2,3) 
    AND stay_on_page_count ORDER BY DESC as second priority, 
    AND login_count ORDER BY DESC as last or third priority
```

i don't know if the pseudo code explains enough, but that's the only thing i can came up with :)

And if its possible, then will it sacrifice performance?
Is there any better approach to accomplish this?

I am using Mysql and PHP (CakePHP 2.x)

Thanks

Comment: Reading your example output, I can't figure out the sorting condition. Could you explain? (pseudo-code is welcome)

Comment: you can do it in the PHP code itself. As per my knowledge there is no simple solution to sort the result as per columns.

Comment: @YaK i have added the pseudo code, hope it explains :)

Comment: I think that your sample output is wrong. I don't see group_id in the output for instance. Is "groups" another table or is "groups" actually "group_id"? Please, edit your question and make sure that all the info in your question is correct.

Comment: So you want to cluster into groups of 4 based on the `stay_on_page_count`, and then within those clusters, order by `group_id`?

Comment: Sorry @littlechad but your last comment does not reflect the order shown in your example. Please either update your question, or explain why item `1, 90mins, 90` is at position 2 (and not position 4).

Comment: @YaK i have edited my question, item 1, 90mins, 90 is at position 2 (not position 4) is because i want the ORDER BY group_id ASC as first priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach (using `summarised` as a table holding the summarised values listed in the question):

```
select * from
(select s1.*, 
        @rank1:=@rank1+1 as rankcalc,
        floor(@rank1/2) rankgroup,
        @rank1%2 rankingroup
 from (select @rank1:=1) r1
 cross join
 (select * from summarised where group_id=1 order by stay_on_page_count desc) s1
 union all
 select s2.*, 
        @rank2:=@rank2+1 as rankcalc,
        @rank2 rankgroup,
        2 rankingroup
 from (select @rank2:=0) r2
 cross join
 (select * from summarised where group_id=2 order by stay_on_page_count desc) s2
 union all
 select s3.*, 
        @rank3:=@rank3+1 as rankcalc,
        @rank3 rankgroup,
        3 rankingroup
 from (select @rank3:=0) r3
 cross join
 (select * from summarised where group_id=3 order by stay_on_page_count desc) s3
) sq order by rankgroup, rankingroup
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/351aa/24).

Note that this solution is dependent on the ordering being evaluated in the sequence specified in the sub-queries, and not overridden by the optimizer - this should work in current versions of MySQL, but may not work in MariaDB (the open source fork of MySQL) or future versions of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

While this will generate the order you want it's very much a forced and hard coded effort.  It makes several assumptions like login_count is always in the ranges you listed.

```
SELECT group_ID, Stay_on_Page_count, Login_Count, myset 
FROM (
SELECT group_ID, Stay_on_Page_Count, Login_Count, 1 as mySet
FROM USERS
WHERE (GROUP_ID=1 and Login_count >= 90) OR (group_ID in (2,3) and Login_Count=100)
UNION
SELECT group_ID, Stay_on_Page_Count, Login_Count, 2 as mySet
FROM USERS
WHERE (GROUP_ID=1 and Login_count Between 70 and 80) 
  OR (group_ID in (2,3) and Login_Count=90)
UNION
SELECT group_ID, Stay_on_Page_Count, Login_Count, 3 as mySet
FROM USERS
WHERE (GROUP_ID=1 and Login_count Between 50 and 60) 
  OR (group_ID in (2,3) and Login_Count=80)
UNION
SELECT group_ID, Stay_on_Page_Count, Login_Count, 4 as mySet
FROM USERS
WHERE (GROUP_ID=1 and Login_count Between 30 and 40) 
  OR (group_ID in (2,3) and Login_Count=70))
ORDER BY myset, group_ID, Login_count Desc
```